# High quality images by CSS

Tags: web, css, media

The iPhone 4.0 has a retina display, you can upgrade web images by using the `background-size` CSS3 property. Not all browsers support CSS3 yet (especially IE), luckely we have the following code to help us out:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) { }
```

But although this code seemed enough for it's purpose, it's not. I would like a statement such as:

```
IF BROWSER SUPPORTS BACKGROUND-SIZE THEN { ... } (in CSS)
```

Why you ask? Well, the Samsung Galaxy S can show really sharp images as well with background-size, but doesn't have a pixel-ratio of 2.0 to trigger the CSS.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you saying you currently add a low resolution background, and then replace it if the device-pixel-ratio is 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for a library like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) :)
Modernizr allow detecting if client support new features (especially css3) or not.

With simple css you can differenciate browser and adapt your code.

Here is the part that you need :
http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#backgroundsize

Oh, also, thank's for your retina tips ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion among the W3C CSS Working Group about [adding feature queries to CSS](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Apr/0428.html).  The proposal is to have a syntax along these lines:

```
@supports ( background-size ) {
  ...
}
```

However, even if accepted, it'll be some years before these proposals reach browsers.  For now you're better off with the modernizr approach described by Tim.